# launch terminator with zsh, and automatically apply "set -o ignoreeof"

Tags: terminal, zsh, gnome-terminator

I am using terminator with `zsh` as my shell:

```
terminator --command="/bin/zsh"
```

Additionally, I need another way to start terminator with `zsh` and make sure that the window does not close on <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>.

I know that I can use `set -o ignoreeof` inside `.zshrc` to prevent <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> exiting the terminal. But that will affect all `zsh` shells.

I don't want to change this globally. One way that I think would be possible, is to have two separate configuration files. But than I would have to maintain two files instead of one. Is there a simpler way to start `zsh` with `set -o ignoreeof` enabled? perhaps specifying this as an option on the commandline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You virtually answered your own question. Just run:

```
terminator --command='/bin/zsh -o ignoreeof'
```

See:

```
info zsh Invocation
```

for details on how to invoke `zsh`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to have `terminator` set some environment variable (if it does not already)

```
env HI_IMA_TERMINATOR=1 terminator --command="/bin/zsh"
```

and then detect that in the ZSH configuration file:

```
if [[ -n $HI_IMA_TERMINATOR ]]; then
    set -o ignoreeof
fi
```

(The above method will not fly if `terminator` cleans out the env for security or other reasons.)